# Is it possible to pay customers with PayPal?

Tags: paypal

Usually with PayPal we buy goods and services by sending money from customer to business.

Now, I want my business to pay my customers; I want to allow them to withdraw money from a virtual wallet on my website.

I did notice there is an 'Adaptive Payments API' which mentioned something vaguely similar to this, but I haven't been able to search up enough information to come to any conclusion.

So is it possible to send money from business to customer (autonomously) with PayPal? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes PayPal has a system for this called Mass Pay read more here https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside a lot of companies use this to pay affilates and customers.

> Don't spend any more time writing checks. Send a Mass Payment instead.
>
> - Send payments to many recipients at once.
> - Send payments to recipients in different countries and currencies.
> - Faster and easier than writing checks.
> - Recipients get paid quickly online. Track payments easily.
>
> Here are some of the many ways you can use Mass Payment:
>
> - Affiliate commissions.
> - Customer rebates.
> - Pay-to-surf rewards.
> - Employee benefits.
> - Survey incentives.

Comment: Excellent! I don't suppose you can find a non-Mass Pay solution? I'm not really going to be sending to multiple people at once.

If not, don't worry! This looks fine.

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the answer if it's helped. No I can't spend more time now looking for any other solution. PayPal works you can send payments manually, with their API, or with Mass Pay.

Comment: Paypal adaptive payments can also be used.  Mass payments needs to be enabled on a per account basis, and is no longer available in all countries.   Mass payments is much cheaper in fees than using adaptive payments.  You can also do ach transfers to your customer's bank account outside of paypal.  Achdirect has an api for this

Comment: @Frank yes a similar question I replied in mentioned ACH or direct deposits. Those are only available in the US and probably Canada. Wire transfers are too expensive and out of the question. PayPal is ideal for most people around the world. If mass payments aren't available in their country I would work with it manually to send payments until integrated with their API.

Comment: Contact Elan Card services.  They will issue debit cards to your USA affiliates or whomever you pay.  You fill these cards via ACH.  You can have your foreign affiliates get an Elan card in the USA.  You fill it in the USA because its a USA account using ach.  The affiliates or payees in foreign countries pay fees at the atm for using a foreign card.   Another option is to use a service like Payoneer.  The problem is when you deal with international the banking gets expensive.    Depending on your product / or service guiding your payees to setup american accounts is the cheapest option.

Comment: PS.  I am almost confident paypal will eventually remove masspay.  Having ACH is a better choice.  paypal has been pushing adaptative payments for the last couple years.  They have already phased out mass pay by requiring you to request to add it to your account. Soon the fees will increase or they will kill it all together.  The flat fee is a lot less than paypal will make on a adaptive payments fee.  Just be aware that paypal will likely pull the plug or maybe grandfather existing accounts only.  WOuld not be the first time for them.

Comment: Turns out the in order to be applicable for MassPay, you need a turnover of at least £5000/month. So for this case, I've had to go with Adaptive Payments using Delayed Chained Pay.